# question about lemma 1 of Crawford & Sobel (1982)

Tags: game-theory, bayesian-game

In [Crawford & Sobel (1982)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1913390), they proved in lemma 1 that for the basic model of a cheap talk game, every equilibrium induces finitely many actions. Here is a special case of their model where the sender's and receiver's utilities are quadratic scores:

- sender's types: $T=[0,1]$
- sender's message space: $M$
- receiver's action space: $A=[0,1]$
- common prior $p$ over $T$ (with the Borel algebra $\mathcal{B}$)
- sender's utility: $u^S(a,x)=-(a-(x+b))^2$, where $b>0$
- receiver's utility: $u^R(a,x)=-(a-x)^2$.

The sender adopts a strategy $\mu: T\rightarrow M$, while the receiver adopts a strategy $\alpha: M\rightarrow A$. Let $\beta$ be the distribution over $T\times M$ given by
$$
\beta(A\times B)=p(A\cap \mu\in B).
$$
We say $(\mu, \alpha)$ is an equilibrium if

- for all $t\in T$, $\mu(t)$ solves $\max_{m\in M} u^S(\alpha(m), t)$
- for all $m\in M$, $\alpha(m)$ solves $\max_{a\in A}\exp_{\beta(.|m)}[u^R(a)]$.

Lastly, we say an action is induced by $(\mu,\alpha)$ if $p\{t: \alpha(\mu(t))=a\}>0$.

In Lemma 1 (p.), C & S prove that, if $(\mu,\alpha)$ is an equilibrium, then it only induces finitely many actions. Here is how I understand the proof goes: for $i\in\{R, S\}$, let $a^i(t)$ be the optimal action of $i$ if $i$ knows that the sender has type $t$. Given our choices of utility functions, $a^R(t)=t$ and $a^S(t)=t+b$.

1. Suppose $(\mu,\alpha)$ induces two distinct actions $a, a'$ at types $t, t'$. WLOG, suppose $a<a'$.
2. Then $t<t'$.
3. Let $h(x)=u^S(a, x)-u^S(a', x)$. Then $h(t)>0$ while $h(t')<0$. By IVT, there is $z$ such that $h(z)=0$.
4. For this $z$, $a<a^S(z)<a'$, i.e. $a<z+b<a'$.
5. So $a$ is not induced by any type $t>z$.
6. Therefore, $a<a^R(z)=z$. Similarly, $z<a'$.
7. So $a'-a>b$.

This finishes the proof. I followed every step until 6. Why should $a<a^R(z)$ follow from the fact that $a$ is not induced by types greater than $z$? I feel I am missing something obvious here...any hint would be greatly appreciated.